# Cummulative Sum functoid in BizTalk map ignoring zeros after decimal point

Tags: biztalk

I am using `Cummulative Sum` functoid but it is ignoring zeros after decimal point.

Eg : If the input is 125.00 then the output is coming as 125 which is not expected. I am expecting 125.00 .

How to get decimal points in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically correct as 125 is the sum of [125.00].

If you need a particular string formatting, that is a different issues.

For that, you would pass the result through a Scripting Functoid which applied a format string, .ToString("#.00") for example, to get the text format you require.

Comment: Thanks lot for your inputs..Will try to format string as you mentioned ..